# Calculate square root of user input number

Tags: python

Write a program that asks for a float from the user, and then applies to it sqrt() 10 consecutive times. Calculate the result in two different ways. (Hint: sqrt() is actually an exponentiation.)

this is what i got:

```
from math import *

def main():
    n = eval(input("Please enter a whole number: "))
    fact = 1
    for i in range(10):
        n = sqrt(n)*fact
    print("In",i+1 , "The sqrt of :", n , "is", n)

main()
```

i want to show like this: for example, input a number: 16

In 1, The sqrt of 16 is 4

In 2, The sqrt of 4 is 2

...
...

In 10 ,The sqrt of .. is ..

please help?

Comment: Heavy hint `sqrt(x) == x ^ 0.5`

Comment: Use `int` (or `float`, if you want to accept floating-point values) instead of `eval`.

Comment: Did you get any further?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your corrected code:

```
from math import *

def main():
    n = float(input("Please enter a whole number: "))
    for i in range(10):
        n = sqrt(n)
        print("In",i+1 , "The sqrt of :", n , "is", n)

main()
```

You needed to convert the user input to a float and the `fact` variable. The `eval` phrase was incorrect.

A "second" way of doing it is using `** 0.5`:

```
def other():
    n = float(input("Please enter a whole number: "))
    for i in range(10):
        n = n ** 0.5
        print("In", i+1 , "The sqrt of :", n , "is", n)

other()
```

Though I don't know why you would ever need it in two ways.

Comment: You mean `**`, not `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the *other*/elegant way to apply the square root n times:

```
>>> def comp_nth_sqrt(x, n):
...     return x**(0.5**n)
... 
>>> comp_nth_sqrt(4, 1)
2.0
>>> comp_nth_sqrt(4, 2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> comp_nth_sqrt(4, 10)
1.0013547198921082
```

If you are using Python2, please use

```
x = int(raw_input())
```

if you are using Python3, please use

```
x = int(input())
```

to get your number. `eval` is not needed and most of the time evil.